# dependency error when run apt-get -f install in debian squeeze

Tags: debian, package-management, aptitude

I can't install or remove packages in Debian. When I type `apt-get -f install` to fix the problem I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
 libgmp3c2 libpython2.6 libssl-dev python-gnupginterface python2.6-dev zlib1g-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
    python-pkg-resources python-setuptools
    Suggested packages:
  python-distribute-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python-pkg-resources python-setuptools
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 190 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/323 kB of archives.
After this operation, 989 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Reading changelogs... Done
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/python-setuptools_3.4.1-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 parse error, in file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control' near line 6 package 'python-setuptools':
`Depends' field, invalid package name `python:any': character `:' not allowed (only letters, digits and characters `-+._')
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/python-pkg-resources_3.4.1-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 parse error, in file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control' near line 7 package 'python-pkg-resources':
 `Depends' field, invalid package name `python:any': character `:' not  allowed (only letters, digits and characters `-+._')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-setuptools_3.4.1-1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-pkg-resources_3.4.1-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've searched a lot but can't solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue until I updated the 3 following packages to the same version: `dpkg`, `dpkg-dev`, `libdpkg-perl`

Before that, I had a mix of version 1.15 and 1.16. I updated all 3 packages to 1.17.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried running?

```
apt-get clean
```

> Clears out the local repository of retrieved package files. It removes
>   everything but the lock file from /var/cache/apt/archives/ and
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/.

Comment: yes.but don't work